# shopify toggle modal on button press

Tags: shopify, liquid

Im a decently experienced developer but this is my first time working with Shopify.

I need to toggle a modal on button press. What is the right way to do this in shopify?

I can easily do this with some javascript but it wouldn't be in the "shopify" way.(Unless it is becaue I have no clue)

I assume it has to do with a variable

```
{% assign showModal = false %}
```

and then on button click, we reassign the variable to true(?)

```
{% if showModal %}
  {% section 'modal' %}
{% endif %}
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Shopify is using the liquid language for outputing data.

The main purpose of liquid is to output some kind of content on the page but the most important part is that it loads BEFORE the DOM loads. This means that you should treat it as a back-end language.

Or to say it simply you can't make front-end interactions lick click/hover/etc.. events and expect to modify the liquid variables.

The liquid code is executed before the DOM loads, so since Javasript fires after the DOM there is no way for the two languages to interact.

Long story short you use only simple JavaScript for front-end interactions.